# PhpStorm - setting setters and getters

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm has a useful feature when quickly creating setters and getters:

```
Code -> generate -> select the items to generate
```

**This is great for setting basic setters/getters.**

However from time to time I want to set more than just setters and getters. For instance I may want to create setters and getters for a one to many or many to many relationship.

i.e.

**Many to many**

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->owner->toArray();
}

/**
 * Set the list of user
 * @param Collection $owner
 */
public function setOwner( Collection $owner )
{
    $this->registeredUsers->clear();

    foreach ( $owner as $item ) {
        $this->owner[] = $item;
    }
}

/**
 * Add merchant to the collection
 * @param Collection $owner
 */
public function addOwner( Collection $owner )
{
    foreach( $owner as $item ) {
        $this->owner->add( $item );
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $owner
 */
public function removeOwner( Collection $owner )
{
    foreach( $owner as $item ) {
        $this->owner->removeElement( $item );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this via the same code generation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ATM PhpStorm does not support such functionality.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25003 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified about any progress (so far it's not planned for any specific future version -- possibly because of very low number of votes -- sort of: no votes = no interest = no need to invest resources into it right now).

Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19891

---

The only alternative I can think of right now (that would use that Code Generation functionality) .. is to modify template for Getter/Setter so that it contains more than one method ([example](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12552)). This way you can generate `setXXX`/`addXXX` as well as `getXXX`/`removeXXX` methods in one go.

Obviously, it would be applied in all cases, so if you need just `get/set` then you would need to manually remove `add/remove` methods -- that's a drawback of such approach.

Note that File & Code Templates could be IDE-wide (`Default` schema) or project-specific (`Project` schema) .. so you may use such combined getters/setters in certain projects only.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/file-and-code-templates-2.html

---

The only other alternative is *half manual* and requires you to use [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm).

- Make actual live template (one time job)
- You need to manually find the place where you want this code to be placed
- Invoke Live Template expansion (so that code template gets inserted)
- Fill all live template variables to complete the code.

With your `addXXX`/`removeXXX` code sample you *may* end up with just filling 1 or 2 template variables (just a quick estimation on what I see; the same variable can be used multiple times so will be filled in few places at the same time; entered text can be transformed (limited set of transformations) so it can be re-used in another variable automatically (e.g. you are typing `owner` and in another place it is used as `Owner` automatically).

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying out live tempaltes. I added one for PHP code however it does not work. Do I need to activate it somehow?

Comment: Screenshots please + describe what you do (where it does not work). Without them it will be just wild guessing (e.g. No context at all .. or wrong context was specified; wrong expand key is used; invalid/wrong live template body etc).

Comment: ntw - all sorted, thanks for your help! Much appreciated and really enjoying having moved to PHPstorm.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
#set ($array = $TYPE_HINT.split('\|'));
#set ($IS_COLLECTION = false);
#set ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE = $RETURN_TYPE);
#set ($NAME_LENGTH = $FIELD_NAME.length());
#set ($NAME_BEFORE_LAST = $FIELD_NAME.length() - 1);
#set ($LAST_CHARACTER = $FIELD_NAME.substring($NAME_BEFORE_LAST, $NAME_LENGTH));
#set ($METHOD_NAME_BEFORE_LAST = $NAME.length() - 1);

#if (${LAST_CHARACTER} == 's')
    #set ($FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME = $FIELD_NAME.substring(0, $NAME_BEFORE_LAST));
    #set ($FIXED_METHOD_NAMING_PART = $NAME.substring(0, $METHOD_NAME_BEFORE_LAST));
#else
    #set ($FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME = $FIELD_NAME);
    #set ($FIXED_METHOD_NAMING_PART = $NAME);
#end

#foreach($hint in $array)
    #if ($hint.toString().contains('[]'))
        #set ($ENTRY_HINT = $hint.toString().replace('[]', ''));
        #set ($HAS_ENTRY_HINT = true);
    #end
#end

#foreach($hint in $array)
    #if ($hint == 'Collection')
        #set ($IS_COLLECTION = true)
        #set ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE = 'Collection')
        #break
    #elseif ($hint == 'ArrayCollection')
        #set ($IS_COLLECTION = true)
        #set ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE = 'Collection')
        #break
    #elseif ($hint == 'array')
        #set ($IS_COLLECTION = true)
        #set ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE = 'array')
    #elseif ($hint.toString().contains('[]'))
        #set ($IS_COLLECTION = true)
        #set ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE = 'array')
    #end
#end

#if ($IS_COLLECTION)
/**
 * @param ${ENTRY_HINT} $${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME}
 *
 * @return ${CLASS_NAME}
 */
public function add${FIXED_METHOD_NAMING_PART}(#if (${HAS_ENTRY_HINT})${ENTRY_HINT} #else#end$${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME})#if(${RETURN_TYPE}): ${CLASS_NAME}#else#end
{
#if ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE == 'Collection')
    if(false === $this->${FIELD_NAME}->contains($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME})) {
        $this->${FIELD_NAME}->add($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME});
    }
#else
    if(false === in_array($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME}, $this->${FIELD_NAME}, true)) {
        $this->${FIELD_NAME}[] = $${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME};
    }
#end

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param ${ENTRY_HINT} $${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME}
 *
 * @return ${CLASS_NAME}
 */
public function remove${FIXED_METHOD_NAMING_PART}(#if (${HAS_ENTRY_HINT})${ENTRY_HINT} #else#end$${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME})#if(${RETURN_TYPE}): ${CLASS_NAME}#else#end
{
#if ($FIXED_RETURN_TYPE == 'Collection')
    if(true === $this->${FIELD_NAME}->contains($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME})) {
        $this->${FIELD_NAME}->removeElement($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME});
    }
#else
    if(true === in_array($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME}, $this->${FIELD_NAME}, true)) {
        $index = array_search($${FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME}, $this->${FIELD_NAME});
        array_splice($this->${FIELD_NAME}, $index, 1);
    }
#end

    return $this;
}
#end
/**
 * @param ${TYPE_HINT} $${PARAM_NAME}
 * @return ${CLASS_NAME}
 */
public function set${NAME}(#if (${SCALAR_TYPE_HINT})${SCALAR_TYPE_HINT} #else#end$${PARAM_NAME})#if(${RETURN_TYPE}): ${CLASS_NAME}#else#end
{
    $this->${FIELD_NAME} = $${PARAM_NAME};
    return $this;
}
```

I've managed to create something like that, feel free to modify upon your needs. This is the **fluent setter** live template.

It works with Doctrine's Collection/ArrayCollection, arrays. Extending this functionality is as simple as creating new **#elseif** statement.

```
/**
 * @var array|string[]
 */
protected $oneField;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|Collection|Another[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Another")
 */
protected $anotherField;
```